# «Разумеется, нет». Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, частицы

Если по аналогии с "конечно да", то получается, что запятая не нужна.
Но я сомневаюсь.

Comment: Все зависит от структуры предложения и вкладываемого смысла. Пишем только "конечно да"? Конечно же — нет. (https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexform&req=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE+%D0%B4%D0%B0) ― Батарея, это, конечно, да...[Владимир Войнович. Жизнь и необычайные приключения солдата Ивана Чонкина (1969-1975)] ― Да, конечно, да! [Вячеслав Рыбаков. Гравилет «Цесаревич» (1993)] В принципе, конечно, да… [Юрий Трифонов. Утоление жажды (1959-1962)]

Answer (score 2):

Что же такое "разумеется"?
Вот информация из толкового словаря Ефремовой:
[разуме́ется](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/235304/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F)
**I** *предикатив*
Оценочная характеристика чего-либо как не вызывающего никаких сомнений, являющегося бесспорным, очевидным.
**II** *частица*
**1.** Употребляется при подтверждении сказанного, подчеркивании категоричности утверждения, соответствуя по значению сл.: да, вне всякого сомнения, конечно, несомненно, а как же, ну а как же.
**2.** Употребляется как вводное слово, выражающее уверенное утверждение и соответствующее по значению сл.: без сомнения, безусловно, бесспорно, несомненно, можно быть уверенным.

Как правило, слово «разумеется» в значении сказуемого встречается в конструкции «разумеется, что...». Перед словом «что» ставится запятая в соответствии с правилами обособления придаточных предложений. Это не наш вариант.

Как же различить частицу (запятая не нужна) и вводное слово (запятая необходима)? Значения-то ведь практически одинаковы.
Возможная подсказка нашлась в словаре-справочнике по пунктуации:
[разумеется](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/617/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F)
**3.** Частица (в ответной реплике). То же, что «да». Обособляется или оформляется как отдельное предложение.

**В подавляющем большинстве** примеров из Нацкорпуса сочетание [**разумеется, нет**](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&g=i_doc&dpp=10&spp=50&text=lexform&req=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82&kwsz=5&mode=main&sr=1&spd=10&nodia=1&out=normal) пишется с запятой (то есть "разумеется" — это вводное слово).
Меня заинтересовал редкий случай без запятой ([И. Ратушинская. Одесситы](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=160728&p=19)):

> Это был сильный удар. Крыть было нечем, и покрасневший Павел только спросил уже в порядке самозащиты:
> — Но тогда, третьего дня, дядя Сергей, вы никак не возражали, мне помнится?
> **— Разумеется нет, мой мальчик.** Я еще не настолько состарился, чтоб не понимать, что в подобных спорах вас никак не интересует мнение дяди-ворчуна, и вообще ничье, кроме вашего собственного.

В этом примере "разумеется", думаю, и выступает в качестве частицы (отдельное предложение; ответная реплика; *мой мальчик* — обращение), имеет значение "да нет" — пауза между словами отсутствует.
На выбор — ставить запятую или нет? — влияет и контекст, и виденье автора.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ:)

Comment: Здравствуйте, Римма! "Виденье" специально так написали? ;) На старый лад?

Comment: Ну... Да мне ТАК привычней. Не является ведь ошибкой, правда? И сейчас вовсю употребляется. _Волгоградские депутаты представляют свое виденье работы облдумы_ (30.09.2019).

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Здравствуйте, Артём! Вы считаете, что нужно поправить на "стандарт"? Возможно, надо добавить в текст расстановку ударений (_разумеется нЕт_)?

Comment: Да нет, не считаю, пусть будет, как вам нравится.) Да, расстановку ударений можно.

Answer (score 1):

Следует различать вводные слова, предшествующие важному, откровенному(слова «конечно» и «разумеется» вношу в этот класс вводных условно), и частицы, как я их называю, категорического пресечения сомнений.

Слова «конечно» или «разумеется» являются вводными, когда они предшествуют чему-то известному или очевидному для воспринимающего речь.

Конечно/разумеется, я уже стар, но я все еще могу выполнять такого рода физический труд.
Конечно/разумеется, мне не победить профессионального боксера, но я просто хочу поучаствовать.

Частицы же категорического пресечения сомнений, как: «правда», «определенно», «конечно», «точно», «безусловно» и тд — категорически пресекают сомнения, ясные из контекста.

— Зачем тебе боксировать с ним, он же профессионал?
— Конечно/разумеется, мне не победить профессионального боксера, но я просто хочу поучаствовать. (Говорящий понимает, что слушателю известно или очевидно то, что предворяется словом «конечно/разумеется».)

— Как думаешь, у тебя есть шансы?
— Конечно/разумеется мне не победить профессионального боксера, идиот, я просто хочу поучаствовать. (Категорическое пресечения сомнений, присутствующих в контексте. Говорящий понимает, что слушателю не известно и не очевидно то, что предворяется словом «конечно».)

— Вы предлагаете при таком диагнозе заниматься спортом?
— Конечно/разумеется, профессиональным спортсменом ваш сын не станет, но тренировки пойдут ему на пользу. (Говорящий понимает, что слушателю известно или очевидно то, что предворяется словом «конечно/разумеется».)

— Ты думаешь, что он не станет профессиональным спортсменом?
— Конечно/разумеется он не станет профессиональным спортсменом: у него средние результаты даже на региональном уровне. (Категорическое пресечения сомнений, присутствующих в контексте. Говорящий понимает, что слушателю не известно и не очевидно то, что предворяется словом «конечно».)

Что касается предложения: «Разумеется нет», то нужно смотреть на контекст.

Могу написать еще примеров, если не понятно.